# IE7 not always rendering control invisible when using filter: alpha(opacity:0)

Tags: asp.net, css, internet-explorer-7

My form does not always render the realupload with the opacity set to 0. Does anyone see anything that I am missing?

```
 <style type="text/css">
   .realupload
    {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        width: 270px;
        right: 0; /* start of transparency styles */
        opacity: 0;
        -moz-opacity: 0;
        filter: alpha(opacity:0); /* IE7 and under */
        -ms-filter: "Alpha(Opacity=0)"; /* IE8 */ /* end of transparency styles */
        z-index: 3; /* bring the real upload interactivity up front */
    }
</style>

<asp:FileUpload ID="realupload" runat="server" Width="75%" OnChange="this.form.fakeupload.value = this.value; javascript: checkFile(); Remove(this); return false;"
                                CssClass="realupload" onkeydown="return (event.keyCode==9);" onpaste="return false;"
                                ToolTip="Click to browse your computer to select the File you would like to import" />
```

Comment: Why are you not using `visibility`?

Comment: did you try putting filter: alpha(opacity:0); before the -moz-opacity: 0;?

Comment: I am using the opacity rather than visibility because I want the control to still be used. I am using a text box to store the value so I can style it with images rather than the standard grey button. I also tried moving the -moz-opacity: 0; with no different results. It seem to render the filters only when it wants to and it does not want to do it every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came, I conquered. I ended up wrapping the fileupload control in it's own div and setting the opacity to 0 on the div rather than the control it's self. This took care of the interment failure of the opacity to render on the control. Thanks for the suggestions guys.

```
    .realuploadcontainer
    {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        width: 370px;
        right: 0; /* start of transparency styles */
        /* Good browsers */
        opacity: 0.0;
        /* IE 8 */
        -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
        /* IE 5-7 */
        filter: alpha(opacity=10);
        /* Safari 1.x */
        -khtml-opacity: 0.0;
        /* Netscape */
        -moz-opacity: 0.0;
        /* end of transparency styles */
    }
    #realupload
    {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        width: 270px;
        right: 0; /* start of transparency styles */
        z-index: 2; /* bring the real upload interactivity up front */
    } 


    <div class="upload">
        <div class="fakeupload">
           <input type="text" name="fakeupload" id="fakeupload" onkeydown="return (event.keyCode==9);"
                  onchange="javascript: checkFile(); return false;" />
        </div>
        <div class=realuploadcontainer>
            <asp:FileUpload ID="realupload" runat="server" Width="100%" AutoPostback="false" 
OnChange="this.form.fakeupload.value = this.value; javascript: checkFile(); return false;" 
onkeydown="return (event.keyCode==9);" onpaste="return false;" 
ToolTip="Click to browse your computer to select the file you would like to import" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You currently have your style set to a class and not an ID. Change `.realupload` to `#realupload` and see if that changes anything.

Comment: it haves runat server, so it change de id, using the class selector is ok

Comment: I realize it has runat=server but that doesn't change the ID on the element unless he is changing it on the server-side code, which he has not said he is. Either way, my comment is still valid and not worth a downvote.

Comment: I'll vote you up on this because this is part of the fix. Using the class reference rather than the ID reference for some reason causes the control to be completely disabled. I did not see that one coming.